# I had this error and I cant solve it. I just want to make a list from oracle database on the web but I cant

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Web app root system property already set to different value: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\SOMUN\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\CRUDWebAppMavenized\] instead of [C:\Users\SOMUN\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\Proje\] - Choose unique values for the 'webAppRootKey' context-param in your web.xml files!
    at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.setWebAppRootSystemProperty(WebUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4633)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

This is web-xml. I think I have error this part but I can't find.

I have error this part but I can't find.

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Search your web-xml for "webAppRootKey", the exception says this is the part where the error occured. The part of web-xml file you sent doesn't include that part.

Comment: <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>webapp.root</param-value>
</context-param>     I added this but it doesnt change.

Comment: The exception says you've set the same value for two different web-xml files. You should check the web-xml files in "C:\Users\SOMUN\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\CRUDWebAppMavenized\" and"[C:\Users\SOMUN\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\Proje\" and give webAppRootKey's param-value different for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.joseph.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Student {





@Id
    @Column
//for autonumber
    private int studentId;
    @Column
    private String firstname;
    @Column
    private String lastname;
    @Column
    private int yearLevel;

    public Student(){}
    public Student(int studentId, String firstname, String lastname,
            int yearLevel) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public int getYearLevel() {
        return yearLevel;
    }
    public void setYearLevel(int yearLevel) {
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }


}
```

-- I found my mistake. My model class and my database table's names were different. they must have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

hi omer I can solve problem: you will open close :)

Comment: is this an answer?